# How can i determine the color of a line in an export file in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

How can i determine the color of a line and have "R" or "G" in an export file in pinescript - trading view

plot(dataseries, text="G")
I have tried many plots.  I always see a number not the value. What I want is a "R" when the line in red and "G" when the line is green, but displayed in the export file